# Starting activity from fragment not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm having an issue with trying to start another activity from a fragment.

The problem I am having is that once I click the button I have set up, nothing happens.

I have 2 fragment classes using 1 layout, fragment 1 and fragment 2(see down below)
I'm trying to start a new activity from a button defined in Fragment 2.

Here's fragment 1 class:

```
public class TabsStuffFragment extends Fragment {

View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_grid_fragment, container, false);
    Button test = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Test.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    return view;

}

}
```

Activity I am trying to open:

```
public class Test extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
}

}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    style="@style/PhotoGridLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="@dimen/image_thumbnail_size"
    android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/image_thumbnail_spacing"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/image_thumbnail_spacing" >
</GridView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="BUTTON" 
    android:clickable="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment 2:

```
public class ImageGridFragment extends Fragment implements
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
private static final String TAG = "ImageGridFragment";
private static final String IMAGE_CACHE_DIR = "thumbs";

private int mImageThumbSize;
private int mImageThumbSpacing;
private ImageAdapter mAdapter;
private ImageFetcher mImageFetcher;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    mImageThumbSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
            R.dimen.image_thumbnail_size);
    mImageThumbSpacing = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
            R.dimen.image_thumbnail_spacing);

    mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity());

    ImageCacheParams cacheParams = new ImageCacheParams(getActivity(),
            IMAGE_CACHE_DIR);

    cacheParams.setMemCacheSizePercent(0.25f); 


    mImageFetcher = new ImageFetcher(getActivity(), mImageThumbSize);
    mImageFetcher.setLoadingImage(R.drawable.empty_photo);
    mImageFetcher.addImageCache(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),
            cacheParams);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_grid_fragment,
            container, false);
    final GridView mGridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    mGridView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView,
                int scrollState) {

            if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING) {
                mImageFetcher.setPauseWork(true);
            } else {
                mImageFetcher.setPauseWork(false);
            }
        }



        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        }
    });


    mGridView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    if (mAdapter.getNumColumns() == 0) {
                        final int numColumns = (int) Math.floor(mGridView
                                .getWidth()
                                / (mImageThumbSize + mImageThumbSpacing));
                        if (numColumns > 0) {
                            final int columnWidth = (mGridView.getWidth() / numColumns)
                                    - mImageThumbSpacing;
                            mAdapter.setNumColumns(numColumns);
                            mAdapter.setItemHeight(columnWidth);
                            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                                Log.d(TAG,
                                        "onCreateView - numColumns set to "
                                                + numColumns);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mImageFetcher.setExitTasksEarly(false);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mImageFetcher.setPauseWork(false);
    mImageFetcher.setExitTasksEarly(true);
    mImageFetcher.flushCache();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mImageFetcher.closeCache();
}

@TargetApi(16)
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    final Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ImageDetailActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(ImageDetailActivity.EXTRA_IMAGE, (int) id);
    if (Utils.hasJellyBean()) {

        ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeScaleUpAnimation(v,
                0, 0, v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());
        getActivity().startActivity(i, options.toBundle());
    } else {
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.clear_cache:
        mImageFetcher.clearCache();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.clear_cache_complete_toast,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Context mContext;
    private int mItemHeight = 0;
    private int mNumColumns = 0;
    private int mActionBarHeight = 0;
    private GridView.LayoutParams mImageViewLayoutParams;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
        super();
        mContext = context;
        mImageViewLayoutParams = new GridView.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
        if (context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(
                android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
            mActionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(
                    tv.data, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return Images.imageThumbUrls.length + mNumColumns;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position < mNumColumns ? null
                : Images.imageThumbUrls[position - mNumColumns];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position < mNumColumns ? 0 : position - mNumColumns;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {

        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return (position < mNumColumns) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {

        if (position < mNumColumns) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = new View(mContext);
            }

            convertView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mActionBarHeight));
            return convertView;
        }


        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) { 
            imageView = new RecyclingImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);
        } else { 
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }


        if (imageView.getLayoutParams().height != mItemHeight) {
            imageView.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);
        }


        mImageFetcher.loadImage(Images.imageThumbUrls[position
                - mNumColumns], imageView);
        return imageView;
    }


    public void setItemHeight(int height) {
        if (height == mItemHeight) {
            return;
        }
        mItemHeight = height;
        mImageViewLayoutParams = new GridView.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mItemHeight);
        mImageFetcher.setImageSize(height);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setNumColumns(int numColumns) {
        mNumColumns = numColumns;
    }

    public int getNumColumns() {
        return mNumColumns;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you plase post the code of the layout that holds this fragment? Can you also please pose the code of the Activity that have this layout?

Comment: I've added the layout and what do you by "pose the code of the Activity that have this layout?" ?

Comment: have you tried a project clean?

Comment: @Jack I'd like to see the code of the main Activity and the code of the layout of the main Activity.

Comment: @RobertoLombardini Yes I've tried cleaning the project and it hasn't solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the Test activity to your manifest? Is there any kind of error or warning in the LogCat? What about adding:

```
Log.d(TAG, "clicked");
```

To your onClick method to check if it is being executed or not?

Comment: What would I put instead of "TAG", it gives me an error "TAG cannot be resolved to a variable". Sorry for being a noob, I never really log before. And yes I have added it to my manifest.

Comment: oh yeah, sorry about that, TAG is usually a String constant, for the sake of testing you can use any String.

Comment: No i'm not getting anything back when I click the button.

Comment: Shall I define the button in my other grid activity class(Fragment 2) instead?

Comment: Oh! I just realized you are using the same layout for both fragments, most likely you are looking at Fragment 1 all the time and you are not setting a ClickListener to the Button there, that's the reason nothing happens, I believe you might be confused on how the fragments are being added to your main Activity, here is the Android reference http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding on how to add fragments, have a look and try to figure out exactly how you want to use Fragments in your Activity and if you really need 2 of them.

Comment: I've decided I don't need 2 fragments. Also, One more quick thing, where would I define the button in the other fragment class I have set up. Where ever I try to define it, I keep getting errors with it conflicting with other code?